# Custom ListView Layout with Multiple ImageViews and TextViews

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have the following XML layout for my ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"/>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Hello"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="Hello"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is what I want to achieve with this XML code (Empty boxes on left/right are images):
[image: What I want]

So far, this is what my code above does:
[image: Current]

I want the second image to appear on the right most side of the view, and have it look like my first example.

**EDIT:**

I have solved my problem and my final working code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Hello"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="Hello"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Hello"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="Hello"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute `android:layout_weight`

Both ImageView will have width 48dp and rest of the space will be divided equally between two LinearLayouts. Exactly like in your photo. You can Align text right in 2nd LinearLayout.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Hello"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Hello"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Hello"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Hello"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer got me what I wanted.

Comment: One thing, for the second `LinearLayout` I kept it as: `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: @Solstice you can keep as it suits you but once you can try to familiarise yourself with layout_weight.  layout_weight=1 means take all the remaining space. If two view have layout_weight=1 that means take remaining space and give half half to both.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `Relative Layout` for that as it cover wide range of screen of different devices.

[image: OUTPUT]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/l1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1" >

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Hello"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Hello"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2" >

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Hello"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Hello"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that out too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make width and height of inner LinearLayout to wrap_content like this.

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Hello"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="Hello"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my question again. I have done that, and the second image appears, but it is not aligned to the right most side of the screen. See my second attached image.

Answer (score 0):

Well in that case, you have to use framelayout. I wont give you direct code because its not necessary. Use these step:

**Use framelayout as your container.** In framelayout, use three another layouts like framelayout or linear layout. add gravity to them as given below:

```
1. android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
2. android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
3. android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check out this code. change the layout_weight property value according to your image size.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:src="@drawable/image"/>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.70">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Hello"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="Hello"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of relative layout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use relative layout for more flexibility and Update your current layout with below code :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Hello"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Hello"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
```